# combined two mysql queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that will return all the gis records that meet a specific inner join constraint:

```
SELECT gis.id_gis, gis.titre, gis.lat, gis.lon FROM spip_gis AS `gis`
INNER JOIN spip_mots_liens AS L1 ON ( L1.id_objet = gis.id_gis AND
L1.objet='gis') WHERE (L1.id_mot = 210118) GROUP BY gis.id_gis
```

I have a second query that will return the `articles.id_article` for a given gis record (in this example gis record 136):

```
SELECT articles.id_article, articles.lang, articles.titre FROM
spip_articles AS `articles` INNER JOIN spip_gis_liens AS L1 ON (
L1.id_objet = articles.id_article AND L1.objet='article') WHERE
(articles.statut = 'publie') AND (L1.id_gis = 136) GROUP BY
articles.id_article
```

How can I extend the first query so that it will also return each record's respective articles.id_article?

I have uploaded the sql schema here: http://pastebin.com/8Fe0Lnx3

Comment: The first thing you could (should) do is format those queries a little better.

Comment: External links are no use.  What have you tried so far?  Do you have some code that's not working?

Comment: user union http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Your both queries are broken. You are trying to directly return the columns that are not included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Both queries are returning the expected records in MyAdmin

Comment: MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you give this query a try and tell me what it returns

```
SELECT gsis.id_gis, gsis.titre, gsis.lat, gsis.lon, articlesGen.id_article, articlesGen.lang, 
articlesGen.titre
from 
(SELECT gis.id_gis, gis.titre, gis.lat, gis.lon FROM spip_gis AS `gis`
INNER JOIN spip_mots_liens AS L1 ON ( L1.id_objet = gis.id_gis AND
L1.objet='gis') WHERE (L1.id_mot = 210118) GROUP BY gis.id_gis) gsis
inner join 
(SELECT articles.id_article, articles.lang, articles.titre,L1.id_gis FROM
spip_articles AS `articles` INNER JOIN spip_gis_liens AS L1 ON (
L1.id_objet = articles.id_article AND L1.objet='article') WHERE
(articles.statut = 'publie') AND (L1.id_gis = 136) GROUP BY
articles.id_article ) articlesGen
on articlesGen.id_gis = gsis.id_gis
```

Comment: Thank you! This query will return the id_gis, titre, lat, lon, id_article for record 136, if I remove "AND (L1.id_gis = 136)", then I get exactly what I was after, the gis records + the article id

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single query it might be complex. One way that I can do is as below:

```
SELECT gis.id_gis, gis.titre, gis.lat, gis.lon, articles.id_article, articles.lang, articles.titre FROM
    (
        SELECT articles.id_article AS id_article, articles.lang AS lang, articles.titre AS titre,articles.statut AS statut FROM
            spip_articles AS articles
            INNER JOIN 
            spip_gis_liens AS L1 
            ON (L1.id_objet = articles.id_article AND L1.objet='article') 
        WHERE (articles.statut = 'publie') AND (L1.id_gis = 136) 
        GROUP BY articles.id_article
    ) AS articles
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT gis1.id_gis AS id_gis, gis1.titre AS titre, gis1.lat AS lat, gis1.lon AS lon FROM
            (
                SELECT gis.id_gis AS id_gis, gis.titre AS titre, gis.lat AS lat, gis.lon AS lon FROM 
                    spip_gis AS gis
                    INNER JOIN 
                    spip_mots_liens AS L1 
                    ON ( L1.id_objet = gis.id_gis AND L1.objet='gis') 
                WHERE (L1.id_mot = 210118) 
                GROUP BY gis.id_gis
            ) AS gis1
            INNER JOIN
            spip_gis_liens AS gis2
            ON ( gis1.id_gis = gis2.id_objet)
    ) AS gis
    ON (articles.id_article = gis.id_gis)
```

The gist is to use `INNER JOIN` recursively over tables to connect each other on the basis of primary keys, say `'id_objet'` and `'id_article'`.
The column names may be updated each time you assign the output table a new name (using `AS`).